# unable to begin a distributed transaction database linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, distributed-transactions

I have a problem with my Linked Server.

I have a Linked Server set up and when I select or insert it works great.

The problem starts when I run a transaction to overwrite simple data in tables.

```sql
begin tran
update [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
set phone = '111111'
where Mobile_phone = '401000010'
rollback
```

I get an error:

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SERVER" returned message "No transaction is active.
> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SERVER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I don't know where the error could be?

Comment: Didn't you ask this on [so] the other day? The image you shared there showed that the feature was switched off; have you enabled it now, and you're still getting the error?

Comment: Ahh yes, you [did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77345276/2029983), and it was [switched off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgLKU.png). I assumed that you switch it on, it worked, and that was why you deleted the question, so if you're asking again I assume that means you have switched it on now?

Comment: What do you mean by turn on?
Turning on what?

Comment: If you are talking about enabling distributed transaction propagation is "TRUE"
but still the same error

Comment: @JanKůst can you add details on your question like sql server version of both instance, are they on the same domain, linked server configuration/security, alias, and on what server are you running the update?

Comment: One server is SQL server 2019, and the second SQL server 2022. Both instances are in same domain. I got an alias on second server intance name is o511data.krks.com and alias is o511data. The second is db1t\edu and alias is db1s - this bothers me if it can't be a problem. Now I set up "promotion of distributed transaction to false". RPC and RPC out is true.

Comment: Someone also wrote here if I type "SELECT @@SERVERNAME, SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')".
The same names should appear, I don't have it like that thanks to the set aliases.

Comment: was the server newly migrated? It doesn't necessarily have to have the same name. If you have a named instance, `@@SERVERNAME` will show you the named instance, while `SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')` will only show the server name.

Comment: According to my information, it was not newly migrated.
I only set the alias for the given server because there was a demand for it so that the full name of the server did not necessarily have to be entered

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same error before when configuring the linked server and using distributed transactions. You need to check the DTC configuration on windows OS level below:

[image]

##### Step:

1. go to `dcomcnfg`
2. expand Component Services
3. expand Computer
4. expand My Computer
5. expand Distributed Transaction Coordinator
6. right click Local DTC, click properties
7. go to security tab
8. copy the config from screenshot above
9. you need to reboot your server

It is also worth checking the firewall rules to see if server communication is open on both ends.

Comment: I have this configuration but a little differently:
I have check allow remote client
                     allow remote administration
                     no auth required
Enable XA transaction and Enable transaction SNA LU 6.2

Comment: do you have the luxury to reboot the server? try the config above then reboot your server.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I will write a request. We'll see if it helps

Comment: @JanKůst Which computer did you configure MSDTC on?...the remote one or the local one or both?

Comment: Same configuration on both

Comment: Rebooted, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Have you check the network config? could you reproduce this issue on a test server? This situation is complex, as it involves a lot of moving parts from the network and os. and sometimes DNS can also influence distributed transactions connection.

Comment: DNS is done by the customer and according to him everything is listed, if it has proven to ping the instances I get responses.
Firewall and enabled DTC are also said to be.

Comment: I was able to repo the issue from my local machine to the test server. However, I haven't found the solution yet. It will take me a few days to figure it out, as I need to involve the network team for a check.

Comment: btw, when I changed the transaction communication manager setting to either _Incoming Caller Authentication Required_ or _No Authentication Required_, a new error message popped up.

Comment: When I have "No Authentication Required" set I get the same error as when I have "Mutual auth"